# Using babel to test react components with Mocha

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, enzyme

I am trying to test a react component with enzyme/mocha and am a bit confused on how to set it up.

Here is the test

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Index from '../../public/js/components/polls/index'

describe("INDEX", function() {
  it("contains a div", function() {
    expect(shallow(<Index />).contains(<div id="index">)).to.equal(true);
  });

});
```

Here is the command I run to start the test:

```
env NODE_ENV=test mocha --compilers js:babel-register --require babel-polyfill --reporter spec --timeout 5000 --recursive
```

And here is the error I get:

```
SyntaxError: /my_app/public/js/components/polls/index.js: Unexpected token (47:10)
  45 |   eachPoll(poll, i) {
  46 |       return(
> 47 |           <Link to={"/poll/" + poll._id} key={poll._id}>
     |           ^
  48 |             <div className="btn btn-info btn-block">
  49 |               {poll.name}
  50 |             </div>
```

The problem seems to be with JSX, but I am able to build this component just fine with webpack. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the file extension `.js` or `.jsx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run Mocha with the babel-register option to run the tests through Babel:

```
--compilers js:node_modules/babel-register
```

Make sure you have a *.babelrc* file in your root directory. It should at least contain the [react](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) preset.

Example for *.babelrc*:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the command to `env NODE_ENV=test mocha --compilers js:node_modules/babel-register --require babel-polyfill --reporter spec --timeout 5000 --recursive` and got the same error

Comment: are you using a `.babelrc` file?

Comment: No react preset? That's not included in the es2015 preset

Comment: That fixed it! If you want to write an answer for that I will approve it.